# Open URL after deployment with Laravel Forge + Digital Ocean

Tags: laravel, deployment, digital-ocean, forge, laravel-forge

I am using Laravel Forge + Digital Ocean to deploy my website from github.

I changed my deployment script a little

```
cd /home/forge/default
git pull origin dev
composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist
php artisan migrate:refresh --force --seed
xdg-open http://url-to-my-domain.com/page-performs-release-tasks
```

Deployment is ok when i leave out the last line (xdg-open). When i paste the last line back the error shows:

```
/home/forge/.forge/provision-4912400.sh: line 7: kde-open: command not found
```

All types i tried give the same error

- xdg-open
- gnome-open
- exo-open
- gvfs-open
- kde-open

What should i put in the deployment script to open a web page in a random browser (and automaticly close it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server has no display. You would have to run a browser on your computer that connects to your server.

You could install something like `lynx`, which is a console based browser, if you need a browser on your server.

It might be better to take the functionality of this URL you want to hit and put it into an artisan command and execute that instead.

Comment: Perfect, i was able to add an artisan command to the deploy script in laravel forge. Works great!